# Uploaded app not appearing in Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I have read several posts on this topic, but have yet to find a definitive answer, so my apologies for asking again.  Based on what I've read, here are some of the oddities of my app - are these to blame for the app not appearing and/or taking hours (going on 3 hours right now for the 1.0.1 to appear in the online Market).

- My app is currently version 1.0 in the Market.  I can only find the app on my Xoom and Galaxy Tab 10.1.  I cannot find it on my OG Droid or Droid X.
- This is the Market link: https://market.android.com/details?id=edu.bsu.android.apps.bconnected
- I built an application based on the Google IO Schedule open sourced app and it includes a "libs" folder with android-support-v4.jar and libGoogleAnalytics.jar.
- Originally this was the top of my manifest:

  ```
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13" />   
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Free app, so I did not check the "copy protection" box.
- I left the default at "all countries"
- In the Market I see this information: "Requires Android: 2.1 and up"

For version 1.0.1, I removed the "uses-features" section entirely and dropped the targetSdkVersion down to 11 - just waiting for the market to update and reflect this new version.

This is my first app in the market, so I'm not quite sure what has gone wrong.  But waiting and waiting for the version to update and then trying to figure out why it won't appear on a rooted OG Droid, a stock Droid X or a T-Mobile phone - I can only see it on my 3.2 Xoom and 3.1 Galaxy Tab.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see from your app page what might be the problem - all I can see is that it's also incompatible with my Desire HD.

You can see the required hardware features by going to the "Edit Application" page of your developer console - this will tell you what hardware features are required by your app. I believe the Market looks at both your manifest and your .APK to determine which devices are supported.

Also, near the bottom of the page you will see something like "**This application is available to over 510 devices.** Show devices" - click on `Show Devices` to see which physical devices your app claims to work on.

Finally, just above this you will see something like:

> ```
> Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
> Required device features
>     android.hardware.touchscreen
> ```

Since your app is only available on your tablets, I suspect you might only see XLARGE (possibly also LARGE) layouts available.

Check the layout resources in the project - you may need to generate layouts for the smaller screens, or use the [`supports-screens`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) options in the manifest, though to be honest, if you've only got layouts for larger screens I think you probably want to create extra layouts to fit the smaller screens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll check the console tomorrow (I'm not the owner of the account, so I need to work through the channels in my department).  I'm pretty sure I have the resource folders set up - I have 12 drawable folders covering hdpi, mdpi, xlarge, land, v11, v12, etc; 4 layout folders and 4 values folders.  But I'll definitely check that those are all present.  The other concern is that it has been over 6 hours and 1.0.1 still has not appeared in the online Market or shown up as update on the Xoom tablet.

Comment: This helped a lot...I used my personal Market account and uploaded (didn't publish) a test copy of my APK.  With my existing manifest, I had about 40 devices (all tablets pretty much).  After removing this uses-feature: android.hardware.faketouch, and reuploading a new APK, that number jumped to 570+.  So, that was my problem - thanks for the help!  Now I just need to get 1.0.2 to appear in the Market tomorrow :)